# PHP array_push causes the script to stop

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, one containing user information and another one containing ids about user from the first array that I don't want to be selected.

I want to insert into a new array data from the first one that are not in the second array.

```
while ( count( $new_array) < 50 ) 
    {
        $index = array_rand($array_1);

        if ( ! in_array( $array_1[$index]['id'], $array_2) ) 
        {
            array_push( $new_array, $array_1[$index] );
            array_push( $array_2, $array_1[$index]['id'] );
        }
    }
```

When data are selected from the $array_1 I insert them in $array_2 in order for it not to be selected again. This works if the while loop does not run more than 12 times, but more than that it runs for more than 30 seconds causing the script to stop. 
What can be the problem?

Comment: Why array_rand()? if you're etrying to merge arrays with noduplicates, it's generally a good idea to loop over the entire array sequentially, not just randomly pick out bits and check if they exist already.

Comment: I'm not trying to merge the arrays, I am picking random winners from the array and saving them in another array. But I don't want to pick the same person more than once

Comment: then how about just using array_shuffle() and picking up the first `n` entries? much simpler than your loop+repetitive check.

Comment: But doesn't prevent the script from picking the same value more than once

Comment: one would presume the original array doesn't have duplicate entries...

Comment: @FlorianShena all you would need to do is remove the array element when it gets chosen by `array_rand()` and you dont have to worry about it being picked twice.

Comment: the problem is that the arrays has duplicate entries

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to keep track of which index has already been randomly selected from array1, just remove that item from the array after it's been selected. If you need to keep the original array unchanged, start by duplicating it.